# Stopping a thread in Spring

Tags: multithreading, spring, executorservice, executor

In my Spring application, I start a thread like this.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextStoppedEvent;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RunBackgroundServices implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private final BackgroundServices backgroundServices;

    private ExecutorService executor;

    @Autowired
    public RunBackgroundServices(BackgroundServices backgroundServices) {
        this.backgroundServices= backgroundServices;
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {

        executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.submit(backgroundServices);
    }

    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStoppedEvent event) {
        backgroundServices.close();
        executor.shutdownNow();
     }
}
```

Here is the thread BackGroundServices.

```
public class BackgroundServices extends Thread {

    @Autowired
    HL7Listener hL7Listener;

    @Autowired
    HISListener hISListener;

    @Autowired
    PollHIS pollHIS;

    @Autowired
    PollPatientPortal pollPatientPortal;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BackgroundServices.class);

    public void run() {
        logger.debug("BackgroundServices :: run");
        try {
            hL7Listener.start();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error(e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }

        try { 
            hISListener.start();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error(e.getStackTrace().toString());
        }

        while (true) {
            pollHIS.start();
            pollPatientPortal.start();
        }
    }

    public void close(){
        hL7Listener.stop();
        hISListener.stop();
    }
}
```

But when I stop the server, the thread continues running in the background. I have no control over the executor, is there a way to stop the thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `shutdown` or `shutdownNow` on an `ExecutorService` will not stop the threads that are currently executing a task. `shutdownNow` will wait for all currently executing tasks to finish. Stopping threads forcibly is a very bad thing, and no well-behaved Java code will do that.

If you want to stop your thread, then you need to pass a signal of some kind to the thread, and your code then needs to read that signal. `ExecutorService#shutdownNow` does half of this for you - it sends an interrupt signal to the currently executing threads. Your code has the beginnings of interrupt handling, but it's not properly implemented.

When you get an `InterruptedException`, you can't just log it and move on - that exception is telling you that your thread has been interrupted, and it needs to finish what it's doing and exit (see [Java theory and practice: Dealing with InterruptedException](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/) - a superb article well worth reading for novices and experts alike). Rather than logging an error when you get `InterruptedException`, your code needs to exit the method (e.g. using `return`).

In your while loop, you then need to check to see if the thread has been interrupted, and exit if it has. So your run method now becomes something like this:

```
public void run() {
    logger.debug("BackgroundServices :: run");
    try {
        hL7Listener.start();
        hISListener.start();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error(e.getStackTrace().toString());
        return;
    }

    while (true) {
        if (Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) {
            logger.debug("Thread interrupted, exiting");
            return;
        }
        pollHIS.start();
        pollPatientPortal.start();
    }
}
```

One last thing - `BackgroundServices` shouldn't extend `Thread`, it should just implement `Runnable`. The `ExecutorService` is treating it as a `Runnable` because `Thread` happens to implement that interface, but `ExecutorService` creates and manages its own threads. Extending `Thread` yourself is just going to result in confusion.